# prevent users from option , checking out with Prevent other users from check out

Tags: tfs

Is there an option in TFS 2010 to prevent other users from checking out files with the following option ?

"Check out- Prevent other users from checking out and checking in."

Comment: Remove the users' permissions to lock the file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks ! Will they be able to still do a check out with the lock type : Unchanged keep any existing lock option ?